# Find row based on set of foreign rows

Tags: mysql

I've got 3 tables for a chat system:

1. **conversation** this table holds an id and timestamp
2. **conversation_participant** tells me which users are in the chat
3. **conversation_message** the messages send within this chat (also holds sender_id)

This setup works quite good for me but now I want to do a 'reverse' lookup. I know which users are going to start a new chat and I want to know if this specific group already has a conversation in the DB. Is there a way to find a row based on a dynamic set of foreign rows?

(preferable without pivot like tricks)

Or is my database design flawed and should I alter that?

```
CONVERSATION
  id int auto_increment
  start timestamp

CONVERSATION_PARTICIPANT
  conversation_id int (foreign key to conversation)
  participant_id int (foreign key to users table)

CONVERSATION_MESSAGE
  id int auto_increment
  conversation_id int (foreign key to conversation)
  author_id int
  time timestamp
  message text
```

Comment: If you have a set of users about to chat, do you want to find the conversation that at least two of have been in or all of them? If there was a conversation between 4 people and 3 are trying to chat now, should that conversation be chosen even though 1 person is not there? Should it be the most recent conversation?

Comment: It should only match the exact same set of users. So 3 people who were in a chat of 4 earlier should start a new conversation. It being the most recent conversation is not relevant since there should only be 1 conversation for each exact set of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you:

- have a list of comma delimited participant_id's -> $list
- know the number of participants -> $qty
- use one of the participants in the WHERE clause -> $participant

*replace those pseudo-variable with real values*

You can see the code here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e90f2/11

Code:

```
SELECT conversation_participant.conversation_id AS conversation_id
  , SUM(IF(members.participant_id IN ($list),1,0)) AS member_count
  , COUNT(*) AS total
FROM conversation_participant
JOIN conversation_participant AS members
  ON members.conversation_id = conversation_participant.conversation_id
WHERE conversation_participant.participant_id = $participant
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING member_count = total
  AND member_count = $qty;
```

FYI: The purpose of the WHERE clause is to limit the number of potential conversations.

Comment: This is brilliant! You even took in account that there could be more users in the list. Thanks!